# return different data type without explicitly specify data type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I want to do something like this:

```
template<class T>
T foo(uint8_t x)
{
    if (x<32) return ((int32_t)1<<x);
    else return ((int64_t)1<<x);
}
```

but I do not want to call `foo<int32_t>(x)` or `foo<int64_t>(x)`. It just doesn't look nice.I want the return type to be automatically deduced correctly.

Intended usage examples:

```
std::max(foo(10),some_variable); // return type of foo need to match some_variable
std::min(foo(32),another_variable);
```

**The solution does not have to be template. If macros can achieve the same, I'm happy to use macros.** Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `foo<X>()` possible ? (I mean is `x` a runtime or compile time value ?)

Comment: it is a run-time value

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible the way you use it. If `T` was used for an argument too, then it would work fine.

Comment: if its the looks that you dont like, then use typedef

Comment: Can you craft code that will demonstrate the intended usage of such a function? If you try, you will find out that it's impossible.

Comment: Because x is a run-time value and templates are compile-time expressions this is not possible.

Comment: By the way, the expression `(int64_t)(1<<x)` will not work as you expect. Because `1` is an `int` the (sub) expression `1<<x` will also be an `int` (or `unsigned int`). The casting will not matter here. You should use `1ULL<<x` to make sure you have a 64-bit expression to start with.

Comment: @someprogrammerdude you don't want the `U`, do you?

Comment: Edited the question. thanks guys.

Comment: @GillBates With bitwise operations, using signed values seldom makes much sense.

Comment: @james As for your edit, it is the `1` that needs to be the correct type, not the `x`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Re " it is the 1 that needs to be the correct type, not the x": Wouldn't the respective other value be converted to the same type within an expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return type of a function (even of a template function) — indeed, any *expression*, if I'm not mistaken, which is why Gill's answer doesn't solve anything —  is a **compile time attribute.** What you want in your code is a **run time decision.** This is a fundamental clash which is not directly solvable (even a typedef wouldn't solve the contradiction, afaics).

What you *can* do is use some sort of handle or container. For example, you can always just return a 64 bit integer which is, in a sense, a base type for the shorter specializations (i.e. you can always cast a short int to a 64 bit int, but not necessarily vice versa).

You could also program something more sophisticated (big num class, polymorphic class, whatever), but the essence would be the same: The return type would be compile-time fixed, and the type would be able to somehow store all possible values, and have some run-time information about what "type" it actually is (if all values are integers, the run time information is the value itself), and possibly come with strongly typed conversion methods.

Answer (score 1):

> The solution does not have to be template. If macros can achieve the
>   same, I'm happy to use macros.

Yes but this doesn't make it any more clean than explicitly telling `Foo` what template type you want.

Anyway, this [can be done](http://ideone.com/pl7arU) but it's not pretty:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

#define FOO(x) (x < 32 ? Foo_32(x) : Foo_64(x)) 

int32_t Foo_32(uint8_t x)
{
    std::cout << "32\n";
    return (int32_t)1<<x;
}

int64_t Foo_64(uint8_t x)
{
    std::cout << "64\n";
    return (int64_t)1<<x;
}

int main() {
    FOO(35);
    FOO(22);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the type of the ternary expression is always `int64_t`, which I think is not what the OP wants. Like with functions, the type of the expression is determined at compile time, and the lesser int gets promoted. As an aside, thou shalt bracket thy macros.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider why would u say its always int64_t?

Comment: @LorenceHernandez Because int64_t is a higher rank than 32 and the `? :` needs equal types for operands 2 and 3 so one of them is promoted.

Comment: @LorenceHernandez The bottom line is that the type not only of function calls but of *all* expressions -- including ternaries -- is fixed, and fixed at compile-time. Ternary conditionals are rather complicated from a language perspective (and handled differently in C and C++ -- in C++ you can assign to some!). The C++11 standard spends 1.5 hard-to-read pages explaining the algorithm for adjusting the type and value category of the operands (and thus of the expression). For arithmetic types the same operand conversion happens as for, say, addition.